# ReactJS, Datepicker Validation from Start Date to End Date

Tags: reactjs, date, validation, datepicker

If we select the start date(in Field Start Date) in datepicker we should not able to select the date before that selected start date in the field named End Date. I want to block the selection of those dates before the start dates. The EndDate field can only shows the dates after the starting dates and we can't able to select the date before it. Need proper example for it.

Comment: as It was solved using momentjs date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass min and max in the normal HTML `input` tag with format `YYYY-MM-DD`. This serves as min and max for date.

To format the date you can use `date-fns` library.

Sample:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { format } from "date-fns";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sDate: "",
    endD: ""
  };
  render() {
    const { sDate } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label htmlFor="sDate">Start Date</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          onChange={e => this.setState({ sDate: e.target.value })}
        />
        <label htmlFor="sDate">End Date:</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          min={format(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ sDate: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Demo Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/j35m9p0p65

Check the sandbox and see once you select the start date all the previous dates are disabled.

Comment: It's easy and simple if we use through moment

Comment: Node JS-: npm install moment. Then, var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();

Comment: `min={format(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")}` @Qbik here

Comment: but what can we do if we want date only from current date to previous 10 years.?